# ORACLE ENGINEER TO RELATIONAL how do i control key names generated?

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys, relational

Working on a school assignment, building databases. First I built my logical model of my database (Using Oracle SQL developer data modeler). There's this little blue arrow button (engineer to relational) which will take your logical model and attempt to create a relational model.

WHEN it does this, it will automatically generate names for your foreign keys. This part infuriates me because it creates these ridiculous named foreign keys, I'm simply looking for a way to turn this feature off (OR I'm open to whatever suave way they actually deal with it) Because so far, I have to go back and meticulously rename all my foreign keys throughout the database.

As a specific example, I have a Client entity, with a unique ID called Client_ID. After the modeler engineers the relational model, it automatically concatenates the name of the entity along with the attribute (for the other entities that have Client_ID as a foreign key).  So even though I'd like my foreign key to simply be Client_ID it creates Client_Client_ID. I've been googling for the better part of the day but I can't find anything related to this.

Comment: nevermind found the answer here https://community.oracle.com/thread/4012092

Answer (score 0):

found the answer here: https://community.oracle.com/thread/4012092

rightclick the source file of your database (its this tree looking model in this window on the left of the modeler).

click settings
naming standard
templates

here you will see its format(s) for keys, constraints,etc where you can customize them
(found this right after i posted question, sorry. Swear it took me hours earlier though)